# How to optimise below postgresql query?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

```
SELECT EVENT_LOG_SUMS.*,
    TOTAL_FTCS.*,
    reg.REGION_NAME,
    reg.TIMEZONE,
    reg.REGION_CODE
FROM REGIONS AS reg
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
    (SELECT
            (SELECT "createdAt"
                FROM MANAGED_EVENT_LOGS AS ev
                WHERE ev.REGION_ID = E.REGION_ID
                ORDER BY "createdAt" ASC
                LIMIT 1) "createdAt",
            REGION_ID,
            SUM(CASE WHEN TYP = 'DATA' AND (E."dst" NOT LIKE '%IP_ADDRESS_HERE%') AND (TRM = 'REMOTE_HANGUP' OR TRM = 'NOT_REGISTERED' OR TRM = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL' OR TRM = 'TIMEOUT') 
          THEN 1 ELSE 0
                END) AS DATA_CCA_TOTAL,
            SUM(CASE WHEN TYP = 'DATA' AND (E."dst" LIKE '%IP_ADDRESS_HERE%') AND (TRM = 'REMOTE_HANGUP'    OR TRM = 'NOT_REGISTERED'   OR TRM = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL' OR TRM = 'TIMEOUT') 
          THEN 1 ELSE 0
                END) AS DATA_X15_TOTAL,
            SUM(CASE WHEN TYP = 'TTY'  AND (TRM = 'REMOTE_HANGUP' OR TRM = 'NOT_REGISTERED' OR TRM = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL' OR TRM = 'TIMEOUT') 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
                END) AS DATA_TTY_TOTAL,
            SUM(CASE WHEN TYP = 'VOICE' AND (TRM = 'REMOTE_HANGUP' OR TRM = 'NOT_REGISTERED' OR TRM = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL' OR TRM = 'TIMEOUT') 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
                END) AS DATA_VOICE_TOTAL,
            SUM(CASE WHEN TYP = 'DATA' AND (E."dst" NOT LIKE '%IP_ADDRESS_HERE%') AND (TRM = 'REMOTE_HANGUP') 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
                END) AS DATA_CCA_SUCCESS,
            SUM(CASE WHEN TYP = 'DATA' AND (E."dst" NOT LIKE '%IP_ADDRESS_HERE%') AND (TRM = 'NOT_REGISTERED' OR TRM = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL' OR TRM = 'TIMEOUT') 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
                END)AS DATA_CCA_FAIL,
            SUM(CASE WHEN TYP = 'DATA' AND (E."dst" LIKE '%IP_ADDRESS_HERE%')AND (TRM = 'REMOTE_HANGUP')
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
                END) AS DATA_X15_SUCCESS,
            SUM(CASE    WHEN TYP = 'DATA'   AND (E."dst" LIKE '%IP_ADDRESS_HERE%')  AND (TRM = 'NOT_REGISTERED' OR TRM = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL' OR TRM = 'TIMEOUT')
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
                END)AS DATA_X15_FAIL,
            SUM(CASE WHEN TYP = 'TTY' AND (TRM = 'REMOTE_HANGUP') 
        THEN 1  ELSE 0
                END)AS DATA_TTY_SUCCESS,
            SUM(CASE    WHEN TYP = 'TTY'    AND (TRM = 'NOT_REGISTERED' OR TRM = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL'   OR TRM = 'TIMEOUT')
        THEN 1  ELSE 0
                END)AS DATA_TTY_FAIL,
            SUM(CASE    WHEN TYP = 'VOICE'  AND (TRM = 'REMOTE_HANGUP'  OR TRM = 'TIMEOUT')
        THEN 1  ELSE 0
                END)AS DATA_VOICE_SUCCESS,
            SUM(CASE    WHEN TYP = 'VOICE' AND (TRM = 'NOT_REGISTERED'  OR TRM = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL')
        THEN 1  ELSE 0
                END)AS DATA_VOICE_FAIL
        FROM MANAGED_EVENT_LOGS AS E
        WHERE 1 = 1
            AND TO_TIMESTAMP(E."tim"::numeric) > reg.EVENT_LOG_DATE
        GROUP BY REGION_ID) AS EVENT_LOG_SUMS ON reg.ID = EVENT_LOG_SUMS.REGION_ID
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
    (SELECT COUNT(ID) AS FTC_COUNT,
            REGION_ID
        FROM MESSAGE_STATUS_INFOS AS msi
        WHERE META_STATUS = '9999'
            AND ALARM_FIRST_STATUS = 'true'
            AND msi."createdAt" > reg.EVENT_LOG_DATE
        GROUP BY REGION_ID) AS TOTAL_FTCS ON EVENT_LOG_SUMS.REGION_ID = TOTAL_FTCS.REGION_ID
WHERE 1 = 1
ORDER BY FTC_COUNT DESC NULLS LAST
```

[Explain images link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl6pH.png) 
[Explain images link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puMyd.png)

```
    [
      {
        "Plan": {
          "Node Type": "Sort",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Async Capable": false,
          "Actual Rows": 49,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Sort Key": [
            "(count(msi.id)) DESC NULLS LAST"
          ],
          "Sort Method": "quicksort",
          "Sort Space Used": 37,
          "Sort Space Type": "Memory",
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Join Type": "Left",
              "Actual Rows": 49,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Inner Unique": true,
              "Join Filter": "(event_log_sums.region_id = msi.region_id)",
              "Rows Removed by Join Filter": 876,
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Async Capable": false,
                  "Join Type": "Left",
                  "Actual Rows": 49,
                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                  "Inner Unique": true,
                  "Plans": [
                    {
                      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                      "Parallel Aware": false,
                      "Async Capable": false,
                      "Relation Name": "regions",
                      "Alias": "reg",
                      "Actual Rows": 49,
                      "Actual Loops": 1
                    },
                    {
                      "Node Type": "Subquery Scan",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                      "Parallel Aware": false,
                      "Async Capable": false,
                      "Alias": "event_log_sums",
                      "Actual Rows": 1,
                      "Actual Loops": 49,
                      "Filter": "(reg.id = event_log_sums.region_id)",
                      "Rows Removed by Filter": 25,
                      "Plans": [
                        {
                          "Node Type": "Aggregate",
                          "Strategy": "Hashed",
                          "Partial Mode": "Simple",
                          "Parent Relationship": "Subquery",
                          "Parallel Aware": false,
                          "Async Capable": false,
                          "Actual Rows": 25,
                          "Actual Loops": 49,
                          "Group Key": [
                            "e.region_id"
                          ],
                          "HashAgg Batches": 1,
                          "Peak Memory Usage": 32,
                          "Disk Usage": 0,
                          "Plans": [
                            {
                              "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                              "Parallel Aware": false,
                              "Async Capable": false,
                              "Relation Name": "managed_event_logs",
                              "Alias": "e",
                              "Actual Rows": 204309,
                              "Actual Loops": 49,
                              "Filter": "(to_timestamp(((tim)::numeric)::double precision) > reg.event_log_date)",
                              "Rows Removed by Filter": 194091
                            },
                            {
                              "Node Type": "Limit",
                              "Parent Relationship": "SubPlan",
                              "Subplan Name": "SubPlan 1",
                              "Parallel Aware": false,
                              "Async Capable": false,
                              "Actual Rows": 1,
                              "Actual Loops": 1244,
                              "Plans": [
                                {
                                  "Node Type": "Sort",
                                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                                  "Async Capable": false,
                                  "Actual Rows": 1,
                                  "Actual Loops": 1244,
                                  "Sort Key": [
                                    "ev.\"createdAt\""
                                  ],
                                  "Sort Method": "top-N heapsort",
                                  "Sort Space Used": 25,
                                  "Sort Space Type": "Memory",
                                  "Plans": [
                                    {
                                      "Node Type": "Bitmap Heap Scan",
                                      "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                                      "Parallel Aware": false,
                                      "Async Capable": false,
                                      "Relation Name": "managed_event_logs",
                                      "Alias": "ev",
                                      "Actual Rows": 7069,
                                      "Actual Loops": 1244,
                                      "Recheck Cond": "(region_id = e.region_id)",
                                      "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
                                      "Exact Heap Blocks": 337808,
                                      "Lossy Heap Blocks": 0,
                                      "Plans": [
                                        {
                                          "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
                                          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                                          "Parallel Aware": false,
                                          "Async Capable": false,
                                          "Index Name": "index_managed_event_log_region_id",
                                          "Actual Rows": 7069,
                                          "Actual Loops": 1244,
                                          "Index Cond": "(region_id = e.region_id)"
                                        }
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "Node Type": "Aggregate",
                  "Strategy": "Sorted",
                  "Partial Mode": "Simple",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Async Capable": false,
                  "Actual Rows": 18,
                  "Actual Loops": 49,
                  "Group Key": [
                    "msi.region_id"
                  ],
                  "Plans": [
                    {
                      "Node Type": "Sort",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                      "Parallel Aware": false,
                      "Async Capable": false,
                      "Actual Rows": 631,
                      "Actual Loops": 49,
                      "Sort Key": [
                        "msi.region_id"
                      ],
                      "Sort Method": "quicksort",
                      "Sort Space Used": 88,
                      "Sort Space Type": "Memory",
                      "Plans": [
                        {
                          "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                          "Parallel Aware": false,
                          "Async Capable": false,
                          "Relation Name": "message_status_infos",
                          "Alias": "msi",
                          "Actual Rows": 814,
                          "Actual Loops": 49,
                          "Filter": "((\"createdAt\" > reg.event_log_date) AND ((meta_status)::text = '9999'::text) AND ((alarm_first_status)::text = 'true'::text))",
                          "Rows Removed by Filter": 729704
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Triggers": []
      }
    ]
```

```
    "Sort  (cost=25630063.56..25630063.68 rows=49 width=181) (actual time=17121.254..17121.258 rows=49 loops=1)"
"  Output: event_log_sums.""createdAt"", event_log_sums.region_id, event_log_sums.data_cca_total, event_log_sums.data_x15_total, event_log_sums.data_tty_total, event_log_sums.data_voice_total, event_log_sums.data_cca_success, event_log_sums.data_cca_fail, event_log_sums.data_x15_success, event_log_sums.data_x15_fail, event_log_sums.data_tty_success, event_log_sums.data_tty_fail, event_log_sums.data_voice_success, event_log_sums.data_voice_fail, (count(msi.id)), msi.region_id, reg.region_name, reg.timezone, reg.region_code"
"  Sort Key: (count(msi.id)) DESC NULLS LAST"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 37kB"
"  Buffers: shared hit=845439 read=1026011"
"  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=73833.02..25630062.18 rows=49 width=181) (actual time=380.272..17121.185 rows=49 loops=1)"
"        Output: event_log_sums.""createdAt"", event_log_sums.region_id, event_log_sums.data_cca_total, event_log_sums.data_x15_total, event_log_sums.data_tty_total, event_log_sums.data_voice_total, event_log_sums.data_cca_success, event_log_sums.data_cca_fail, event_log_sums.data_x15_success, event_log_sums.data_x15_fail, event_log_sums.data_tty_success, event_log_sums.data_tty_fail, event_log_sums.data_voice_success, event_log_sums.data_voice_fail, (count(msi.id)), msi.region_id, reg.region_name, reg.timezone, reg.region_code"
"        Inner Unique: true"
"        Join Filter: (event_log_sums.region_id = msi.region_id)"
"        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 876"
"        Buffers: shared hit=845439 read=1026011"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=43553.00..24145654.30 rows=49 width=165) (actual time=286.424..12527.941 rows=49 loops=1)"
"              Output: reg.region_name, reg.timezone, reg.region_code, reg.event_log_date, event_log_sums.""createdAt"", event_log_sums.region_id, event_log_sums.data_cca_total, event_log_sums.data_x15_total, event_log_sums.data_tty_total, event_log_sums.data_voice_total, event_log_sums.data_cca_success, event_log_sums.data_cca_fail, event_log_sums.data_x15_success, event_log_sums.data_x15_fail, event_log_sums.data_tty_success, event_log_sums.data_tty_fail, event_log_sums.data_voice_success, event_log_sums.data_voice_fail"
"              Inner Unique: true"
"              Buffers: shared hit=839167 read=179585"
"              ->  Seq Scan on public.regions reg  (cost=0.00..7.49 rows=49 width=61) (actual time=0.031..0.072 rows=49 loops=1)"
"                    Output: reg.id, reg.region_name, reg.region_code, reg.is_annotation, reg.system_operator, reg.projects, reg.carrier, reg.wireless_tech, reg.cf_status, reg.created_by, reg.""createdAt"", reg.""updatedAt"", reg.fail_to_checkin_frequency, reg.is_default, reg.fail_to_checkin_day, reg.fail_to_checkin_hour, reg.fail_to_checkin_minute, reg.timezone, reg.battery_low_level, reg.battery_high_level, reg.second_report_call_time, reg.report_generation_time, reg.apn_level, reg.email_subject, reg.email_text, reg.email_signature, reg.event_log_date"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=7"
"              ->  Subquery Scan on event_log_sums  (cost=43553.00..501672.46 rows=1 width=120) (actual time=255.668..255.668 rows=1 loops=49)"
"                    Output: event_log_sums.""createdAt"", event_log_sums.region_id, event_log_sums.data_cca_total, event_log_sums.data_x15_total, event_log_sums.data_tty_total, event_log_sums.data_voice_total, event_log_sums.data_cca_success, event_log_sums.data_cca_fail, event_log_sums.data_x15_success, event_log_sums.data_x15_fail, event_log_sums.data_tty_success, event_log_sums.data_tty_fail, event_log_sums.data_voice_success, event_log_sums.data_voice_fail"
"                    Filter: (reg.id = event_log_sums.region_id)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 25"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=839160 read=179585"
"                    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=43553.00..501671.95 rows=41 width=120) (actual time=227.895..255.659 rows=25 loops=49)"
"                          Output: (SubPlan 1), e.region_id, sum(CASE WHEN (((e.typ)::text = 'DATA'::text) AND ((e.dst)::text !~~ '%IP_ADDRESS_HERE%'::text) AND (((e.trm)::text = 'REMOTE_HANGUP'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'NOT_REGISTERED'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'TIMEOUT'::text))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), sum(CASE WHEN (((e.typ)::text = 'DATA'::text) AND ((e.dst)::text ~~ '%IP_ADDRESS_HERE%'::text) AND (((e.trm)::text = 'REMOTE_HANGUP'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'NOT_REGISTERED'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'TIMEOUT'::text))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), sum(CASE WHEN (((e.typ)::text = 'TTY'::text) AND (((e.trm)::text = 'REMOTE_HANGUP'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'NOT_REGISTERED'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'TIMEOUT'::text))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), sum(CASE WHEN (((e.typ)::text = 'VOICE'::text) AND (((e.trm)::text = 'REMOTE_HANGUP'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'NOT_REGISTERED'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'TIMEOUT'::text))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), sum(CASE WHEN (((e.typ)::text = 'DATA'::text) AND ((e.dst)::text !~~ '%IP_ADDRESS_HERE%'::text) AND ((e.trm)::text = 'REMOTE_HANGUP'::text)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), sum(CASE WHEN (((e.typ)::text = 'DATA'::text) AND ((e.dst)::text !~~ '%IP_ADDRESS_HERE%'::text) AND (((e.trm)::text = 'NOT_REGISTERED'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'TIMEOUT'::text))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), sum(CASE WHEN (((e.typ)::text = 'DATA'::text) AND ((e.dst)::text ~~ '%IP_ADDRESS_HERE%'::text) AND ((e.trm)::text = 'REMOTE_HANGUP'::text)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), sum(CASE WHEN (((e.typ)::text = 'DATA'::text) AND ((e.dst)::text ~~ '%IP_ADDRESS_HERE%'::text) AND (((e.trm)::text = 'NOT_REGISTERED'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'TIMEOUT'::text))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), sum(CASE WHEN (((e.typ)::text = 'TTY'::text) AND ((e.trm)::text = 'REMOTE_HANGUP'::text)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), sum(CASE WHEN (((e.typ)::text = 'TTY'::text) AND (((e.trm)::text = 'NOT_REGISTERED'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'TIMEOUT'::text))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), sum(CASE WHEN (((e.typ)::text = 'VOICE'::text) AND (((e.trm)::text = 'REMOTE_HANGUP'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'TIMEOUT'::text))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), sum(CASE WHEN (((e.typ)::text = 'VOICE'::text) AND (((e.trm)::text = 'NOT_REGISTERED'::text) OR ((e.trm)::text = 'ESTABLISH_FAIL'::text))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)"
"                          Group Key: e.region_id"
"                          Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 32kB"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=839160 read=179585"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on public.managed_event_logs e  (cost=0.00..22637.00 rows=132800 width=53) (actual time=0.008..107.628 rows=204309 loops=49)"
"                                Output: e.id, e.""createdAt"", e.""updatedAt"", e.original_message, e.region_code, e.ani_number, e.logs_id, e.region_id, e.call_box_id, e.idx, e.ev, e.tim, e.start_time, e.end_time, e.typ, e.dst, e.trm, e.txt, e.message_id, e.manually_set_start_time"
"                                Filter: (to_timestamp(((e.tim)::numeric)::double precision) > reg.event_log_date)"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 194091"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=490392 read=179585"
"                          SubPlan 1"
"                            ->  Limit  (cost=11173.62..11173.62 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1.103..1.103 rows=1 loops=1244)"
"                                  Output: ev.""createdAt"""
"                                  Buffers: shared hit=348768"
"                                  ->  Sort  (cost=11173.62..11189.10 rows=6193 width=8) (actual time=1.102..1.102 rows=1 loops=1244)"
"                                        Output: ev.""createdAt"""
"                                        Sort Key: ev.""createdAt"""
"                                        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB"
"                                        Buffers: shared hit=348768"
"                                        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.managed_event_logs ev  (cost=72.42..11142.66 rows=6193 width=8) (actual time=0.117..0.813 rows=7069 loops=1244)"
"                                              Output: ev.""createdAt"""
"                                              Recheck Cond: (ev.region_id = e.region_id)"
"                                              Heap Blocks: exact=337808"
"                                              Buffers: shared hit=348768"
"                                              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_managed_event_log_region_id  (cost=0.00..70.87 rows=6193 width=0) (actual time=0.097..0.097 rows=7069 loops=1244)"
"                                                    Index Cond: (ev.region_id = e.region_id)"
"                                                    Buffers: shared hit=10960"
"        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=30280.02..30293.48 rows=37 width=24) (actual time=93.693..93.737 rows=18 loops=49)"
"              Output: count(msi.id), msi.region_id"
"              Group Key: msi.region_id"
"              Buffers: shared hit=6272 read=846426"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=30280.02..30284.39 rows=1745 width=32) (actual time=93.686..93.700 rows=631 loops=49)"
"                    Output: msi.region_id, msi.id"
"                    Sort Key: msi.region_id"
"                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 88kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=6272 read=846426"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on public.message_status_infos msi  (cost=0.00..30186.07 rows=1745 width=32) (actual time=0.026..93.524 rows=814 loops=49)"
"                          Output: msi.region_id, msi.id"
"                          Filter: ((msi.""createdAt"" > reg.event_log_date) AND ((msi.meta_status)::text = '9999'::text) AND ((msi.alarm_first_status)::text = 'true'::text))"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 729704"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=6272 read=846426"
"Planning Time: 1.115 ms"
"Execution Time: 17121.457 ms"
```

Comment: Without a query plan is not very useful to search for any optimizations. Could you please share the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this statement and all DDL (including indexes) for the tables involved? (and all in plain text, not images)

Comment: Like I said, no image please. There is nothing I can copy/paste from an image to proces the results. Use plain text. And use the original plan, not the output from some tool that obscures all important information. And also the DDL for all tables and indexes.

Comment: And the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)  ? And the DDL?

Comment: If `MANAGED_EVENT_LOGS."tim"` is indexed, your transformation in the where clause probably precludes the planner from using it.  Transform `reg.EVENT_LOG_DATE` instead of `E."tim"`:
`AND E."tim" > reg.EVENT_LOG_DATE::WhateverDataType_tim_Is`

Similarly, if `MESSAGE_STATUS_INFOS.META_STATUS` is an int, don't quote `9999` , and if `ALARM_FIRST_STATUS` is a boolean, don't quote `true`

Comment: @FrankHeikens EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) added.

Comment: What version are you running?  Can you simplify things as much as possible while retaining the slowness, like try getting rid of the last lateral join, and all of those CASE expressions, which probably don't cause the slowness but do complicate reading the plan.

Comment: Lots of sequential scans. Are the tables you are querying indexed and if so are they indexed on the columns you are joining on. ?